# btrfs compression effects on cache and writes

Tags: filesystems, compression

I'm trying to get a better understanding of btrfs compression. I've seen this useful post in reddit
(www.reddit.com/r/linux/comments/1mn5zy/), from which I gather compresison is done for extents, i.e. 150KB size units. I'm trying to understand:

1. small random writes - does a small random write cause the entire extent to be re-compressed and re-written to disk?
2. page cache - are the extents saved in their compressed form in the page cache, and decompressed on demand? if so, this saves a lot of RAM at the cost of repeated decompression (i.e. CPU time)